# Using require with casperjs returns "Can't find module" error

Tags: require, casperjs

I'm following the documentation on [writing a module with casperjs](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/writing_modules.html), but I'm getting an error.

The code, straight from the docs:

```
// my module, stored in universe.js
// patching phantomjs' require()
var require = patchRequire(require);

// now you're ready to go
var utils = require('utils');
var magic = 42;
exports.answer = function() {
    return utils.format("it's %d", magic);
};
```

And the calling script:

```
var universe    = require("./universe");
var casper      = require("casper").create();


console.log(universe.answer());

casper.test.begin("Home Page", 1, function suite(test) {

});
```

But I get the following error:

```
casperjs test testStage.js
Test file: testStage.js
CasperError: Can't find module ./universe
  /usr/local/Cellar/casperjs/1/libexec/bin/bootstrap.js:214 in patchedRequire
  /Users/smosk/Google Drive/source/nest/testStage.js:1
FAIL CasperError: Can't find module ./universe
#    type: error
#    file: testStage.js
#    subject: false
#    error: "CasperError: Can't find module ./universe"
#    stack: in patchedRequire() in /usr/local/Cellar/casperjs/1/libexec/bin/bootstrap.js:214
in anonymous() in testStage.js:1
FAIL 1 test executed in 0.031s, 0 passed, 1 failed, 0 dubious, 0 skipped.

Details for the 1 failed test:

In testStage.js
  Untitled suite in testStage.js
    error: CasperError: Can't find module ./universe
```

Also tried defining casper first:

```
var casper      = require("casper").create();
var universe    = require("./universe");
```

But that just resulted in

```
Test file: testStage.js
CasperError: Can't find module ./universe
  /usr/local/Cellar/casperjs/1/libexec/bin/bootstrap.js:214 in patchedRequire
  /Users/smosk/Google Drive/source/nest/testStage.js:2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try to upgrade to the lastest master build of CasperJS as this [pull request](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/pull/561) that I made should fix the problem that you're having.

However, if you don't want to upgrade, you could also try running CasperJS with the following:

```
casperjs test ./testStage.js
```

Answer (score 4):

for others who might be an idiot like me, you may want to make sure you are using casperjs in your cmd and not phantomjs

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem. Mine seems to have been caused by the merge of https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/issues/587 . Going back to 1d1e83ba3c9241623 solved my problems

Answer (score 1):

I just spent the last 2 hours trying to debug this issue:

```
C:\casperjs>casperjs
CasperError: Can't find module cli

  C:\casperjs\bin\bootstrap.js:262 in patchedRequire
  C:\casperjs\bin\bootstrap.js:375
  C:\casperjs\bin\bootstrap.js:395
```

I was using PhantomJS 1.9.0 but I found I had to upgrade to 1.9.2 and it started working immediately. I hope this is helpful to someone else.

Comment: so the conclusion is,... phantomJS 1.9.2 is only working with casperjs 1.1 and not the lower version of them? @Steve Rukuts

Comment: I'm very sorry @gumuruh but I'm now unsure. I think that's right but I haven't used CasperJS in a while now. If you'll look at the date you'll notice that the post in question is almost 3 years old so I'd certainly look at more recent documentation.